# Z-index issue with external video player

Tags: wordpress, html, css, z-index

I have a problem with my website, for example: https://filmowo.co/odcinki/marvel-cloak-i-dagger-1x1/ when you open the player in fullscreen mode there are site elements under the video. Beware of ads. Here is a screen also:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYRP0.jpg)
 I was only able to fix the header which has fixed position but with the content section its not working. Can you please take a look? I think its pretty easy but Im not css specialist :)

update:
this is the element that need to be modified, any ideas? https://i.snag.gy/YHy4Ns.jpg

Comment: Is the element with z-index positionned?

Comment: Hello, thanks for respond - https://snag.gy/a6JdG3.jpg 
This is how it looks like, even the wordpress admin panel is above the player. I cant change the css of the player, tried to setup various index to elements but with no result

Comment: Because z-index only works on positioned elements. This is wordpress? You should tag wordpress in your question to have more chances to receive an answer.

Comment: Yes it its, will edit thanks. I tried with position: relative !important;
    z-index: 0 !important; to the main content div but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there was an issue with animate.css plugin which I used to animate a player while loading.